# How to fix "ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found" on Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed Android Studio 3.3 and Java on my computer, when I opened a new project instantly I got this error.

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'testImplementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'My Application' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.0 and sync project

The project 'My Application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

When I tried to update manually, I downloaded gradle 5.4.0 and installed manually. (Also I checked on cmd to see its version.)

Then I changed

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

These code to gradle:5.4.0 I got still same error. How can I fixed it?

```
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your app/build.gradle.   And use android gradle plugin version as '3.4.0' and gradle version as '5.1.1'. android gradle plugin version is mentioned in project_folder/build.gradle and gradle version is mentioned project_folder/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: [link](https://github.com/theorycraft/androiderrors/blob/master/build.gradle) Sorry for beign late. Iam a newbie at this community and I trying to get used to it. Here you can see my github link and project_folder/build.gradle. I'll be happy if you can help me to get rid off it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **application/build.gradle** shall be on this line(see gradle plugin version as 3.4.0)

Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2. application/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties shall be on this line(see gradle version as 5.1.1)

## Sun Mar 24 01:41:54 IST 2019

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

3. No issue with your `application/app/build.gradle`(which you posted on github)

Answer (score 4):

If you've a Turkish workstation, then change in build.gradle:

`testImplementation` -> `testİmplementation`
`androidTestImplementation` -> `androidTestİmplementation`
`androidTestImplementation` -> `androidTestİmplementation`